# Disk attachment issue in azure scaleset VM

Tags: azure

I am using command to create and attach disk at the time of VM creation in azure scaleset.

az az disk create --options
az vmss disk attach --options

the first command creates disk but when the second command starts, it keeps on running. Disk gets attached but it never release the execution of "az vmss disk attach" command.So the custom script times out after couple of hours.

Any idea, why this happens so.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did the test, was able to create disk and attach it to vm scale set. Check below -

[image]

[image]

I got no issues. Please check if you are running similar commands.

Comment: Hi, I mentioned that it works quite fine in a running VM but not at the startup of VM using custom script.